# Problems with 'if' statements

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, nested

I've been trying to debug this code but can't seem to figure out why even though the condition has been met (e.g. findTitle.equals(title)); it still moves over to the 'else' condition. Everything looks pretty straight-forward and it seems correct. Any insights into this?

```
private void addNewMs() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String title = Helper.readString("Enter movie title > ");
    String theatre = Helper.readString("Enter theatre name > ");
    Theatre Art = null;


        for (int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++){
            String findTitle = movies.get(i).getTitle();
            if (findTitle.equals(title)){
                for (int a = 0; a < theatres.size();a++){
                    String findTheatre = theatres.get(a).getName();
                    if (findTheatre.equals(theatre)){
                        Art = theatres.get(a);
                        Movie m = movies.get(i);
                        int year = Helper.readInt("Enter year > ");
                        int month = Helper.readInt("Enter month > ");
                        int day = Helper.readInt("Enter day > ");
                        int hours = Helper.readInt("Enter hour > ");
                        int mins = Helper.readInt("Enter mins > ");
                        Date d = Helper.thisDate(year, month, day, hours, mins);
                        MovieScreening newScreening = new MovieScreening(d, m, Art, 0);
                        screenings.add(newScreening);
                        System.out.println("Added Successfully.");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Movie and/or Theatre not found.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Movie and/or Theatre not found.");
                break;

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Print out the value of `findTheatre` and `theatre`.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html - Split up your code into smaller chunks and methods and I bet you spot the issue.

Comment: gave us and example out/input you got

Comment: Proper way to iterate a collection is using `Iterator`, you can use `for-each` loop for readability

Comment: You can check whether movies or theatres are empty or not this way: theatres.isEmpty()

Comment: Maybe your readString method add extra char, like Line Feed? Print out the value of findTheatre and theatre

Answer (score 5):

You use the else clause in the loop, so it executes each time you consider a movie or theatre is not the same as what you entered. Instead use a flag to indicate that the movie and theatre was found and if that is not set then provide a status message once you exit the entire for loop:

```
boolean found = false;
for (...) {
    if (movie ...) {
        if (theatre ...) {
            found = true;
        }
     }
 }
 if (!found) {
     System.out.println("Movie ...");
 }
```

Comment: +1 For actually reading the code and thinking about what it's supposed to do.